# How to click on "Logout" which is present inside td

Tags: testing, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Que: How to click on "Logout" which is present inside dropdown

```
 <tr id="dijit_MenuItem_55" class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" dojoattachevent="onmouseenter:_onHover,onmouseleave:_onUnhover,ondijitclick:_onClick" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" dojoattachpoint="focusNode" aria-labelledby="dijit_MenuItem_55_text dijit_MenuItem_55_accel" style="-moz-user-select: none;" widgetid="dijit_MenuItem_55">
<tr id="dijit_MenuItem_56" class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" dojoattachevent="onmouseenter:_onHover,onmouseleave:_onUnhover,ondijitclick:_onClick" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" dojoattachpoint="focusNode" aria-labelledby="dijit_MenuItem_56_text dijit_MenuItem_56_accel" style="-moz-user-select: none;" widgetid="dijit_MenuItem_56">
<td class="dijitReset dijitMenuItemIconCell" role="presentation">
<td id="dijit_MenuItem_56_text" class="dijitReset dijitMenuItemLabel" dojoattachpoint="containerNode" colspan="2">Logout</td>
```

I have tried with

```
driver.findElement(By.id("processPortalUserDropdown")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Logout")).click();
OR
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("Logout")).click();
```

but it is not working

NOte :

1.I cant use id= dijit_MenuItem_56_text as it changes dynamically for every login or after performing any functionality in the site.

2.I have tried with

```
   new     Select(driver.findElement(By.id("processPortalUserDropdown"))).selectByVisibleText("Logout"        );
```

but it displaying error message as

```
 FAILED: testQTO01
   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been      "select" but was "div"
    Build info: version: '2.37.0', revision: 'a7c61cb', time: '2013-10-18 17:15:02'
   System info: host: 'TSSGMSL060', ip: '10.56.40.138', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch:       'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_40'
    Driver info: driver.version: unknown
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.<init>(Select.java:46)
at Com.Tss.Qto.QTO01.testQTO01(QTO01.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Please anyone give me a solution for this ?..it will be great help..
Thanking in advance.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, you are using the `Select` class which is used for `select` HTML elements only. It sounds like it isn't a dropdown per se, but merely styled as one, which tricked you into thinking it's a dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("processPortalUserDropdown"))).selectByVisibleText("Logout")
```

Answer (score 0):

try driver.findElement(By.id("dijit_MenuItem_56_text")).click();

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.Click(driver.findElement(By.id("processPortalUserDropdown")))
    .Click(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Logout")))
    .Click()
    .Perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this locator //td[contains(text(),'Logout')]

oASelFW.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'Logout')]")).click();